# Ada path query -- this time with gnatmake

Tags: ada

Trying to build the example code in `ada-util`. So i'm running

`gnatmake json.adb` inside the `ada-util/samples/` directory.

However I get the following error:

```
 gnatmake json.adb 
gcc -c json.adb
json.adb:21:06: file "util.ads" not found
json.adb:23:06: file "util.ads" not found
json.adb:23:06: "Json (body)" depends on "Mapping (spec)"
json.adb:23:06: "Mapping (spec)" depends on "Util (spec)"
json.adb:24:06: file "util.ads" not found
json.adb:25:06: file "util.ads" not found
json.adb:26:06: file "util.ads" not found
gnatmake: "json.adb" compilation error
```

So there's clearly something wrong with my path because I've installed `ada-util` and I can confirm that `util.ads` is in the install directory. Now, clearly there's something going wrong here as this isn't the first PATH issue I've had with Ada recently. Where is it supposed to be installed? As currently it's under `/opt/GNAT/2020/include/utilada_core.static/util.ads` where the `GNAT` install lives.

Questions:

1. Where should it be if not here?
2. Do I have to tell `gnatmake` where it is and if so how - couldn't see in the docs
3. If so, why do I have to tell `gnatmake` where it is given I followed the install instructions -- is that a bug in the install process or is something else going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Looks for me, like the library is in proper place.
2. As you guess properly, you have to tell it where the library is located. As far I see, in the root directory of the project, there is the file `samples.gpr`. Thus, if you want to build samples, you have to execute in the root directory of the project:

   ```
   gnatmake -P samples.gpr
   ```

   Or, if you are in samples directory (like in your example):

   ```
   gnatmake -P ../samples.gpr
   ```

   This should build all samples.
3. By default, `gnatmake` can't find needed libraries, same as GCC can't find extra libraries for C/C++ projects. It is generally done by GNAT Project files (these one with `.gpr` extension, easy way) or via compilation flags (hard way) or Makefiles. The Ada compilation process is similar to the C/C++. It also needs a lot of flags, settings and sometimes, for a bigger project not working out of the box. :)